# Rails 3 : Increment Manually a field with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

i'm begining with the gem mongoid in rails3 .

I want to know how i can increment manually a field containing an integer.

I've tried a lot of method but no one work well.

And i'd like to know if this action can be done in an atomic context ?

Comment: inc function is atomic, but not thread safe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*For Mongoid versions previous to 4*

from the mongoid docs, assuming that a Person model has an Integer field of 'score', this would increment the score by 100:

```
person = Person.find(id)
person.inc(score: 100) # Increment score
```

more info: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html#atomic

Comment: should be person.inc(score: 100)

Comment: depending on the mongid version you use, it takes either a hash or a field name + value. Change is as of Mongoid 4.0.0: https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 4):

**Correct Answer For Mongoid 4.0+**

```
person = Person.find(id)
person.inc(score: 100)
```

Comment: Depends on the mongoid version you use.  Your answer is good for 4.0+, but doesn't work in earlier versions.